# I want to connect MetaMask to my website. what is the code?

Tags: metamask

I want to connect my website to my Metamask wallet, I need the code that makes a button connect in my website to connect with My Metamask? what is the code? where shall I add it? in which file on my website? which line? I need help.

regards

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the developer doc getting started https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html

Comment: I have taken a look at these docs. but which code is correct? where shall I add them? I wish if those developers add screenshots to which directory they have to add these codes, or which file, which line and so. details important for people like us.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused with it too earlier, but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzdMosLzj80) video helped me.

So you can `truffle unbox react` in some test folder and get an idea of how it is done. At least it helped me!